# timescaledb data persistance in a docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, timescaledb

I can run a timescaledb database using the Docker compose script:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  timescaledb:
    image: timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg12
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      TIMESCALEDB_TELEMETRY: off
      POSTGRES_USER: timescaledb
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
```

The data stored in here is not persistant however. So when I reset the computer I lose it all. I am trying to instead trying to make the volume persistant by mapping the /var/lib/postgresql/data folder to something on my local drive (which is on the windows OS).

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  timescaledb:
    image: timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg12
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      TIMESCALEDB_TELEMETRY: off
      POSTGRES_USER: timescaledb
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - postgresdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  postgresdata:
    external: false
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/data/db-data'
```

I get the error though

> "initdb: error: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" exists but is not empty
> If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty
> the directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" or run initdb
> with an argument other than "/var/lib/postgresql/data""

I can see (when I run the container the first way with nonpersistant data) that there are alot of postgres files contained in /var/lib/postgresql/data. My guess then is that at the build stage /var/lib/postgresql/data is made and my volumes statement is not allowed to override all of this data. I am not sure the best way to overcome this.

So how do I get docker compose to cooperate with a volume stored on the host machine?

Answer (score 1):

Use volume mapping as below

```
volumes:
      - postgresdata:/home/postgres/pgdata/data/
```

Reference : https://docs.timescale.com/self-hosted/latest/install/installation-docker/#install-self-hosted-timescaledb-from-a-pre-built-container